# Find sum of series $n\ n!$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't know where to start, all I am able to achieve is:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^k n\ n! =  \sum\limits_{n=1}^k n(n-1)! $

Thanks to Wolfram I know the solution and it's $(1 + k)! -1$, but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Try to add and subtract $i!$ on the LHS, you will end up with $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (i+1)!-i!$

Comment: @Dav2357 With a sum index $i$?

Comment: Every identity of the form $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)=g(n)$ can be proved by verifying both (i) $f(1)=g(1)$ and (ii) $f(n+1)=g(n+1)-g(n)$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut right I suppose it is more like $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i*i!$

Comment: Writing $\sum_{n=1}^n$ should be banned by law.

Comment: It is not clear what your sums, or the supposed equality, are supposed to mean.  Maybe you could write it out explicitly for, say, $n=3$?

Comment: The edit clarifies each sum separately, but not the reported equality.

Comment: @lulu https://imgur.com/a/T5JhXjl First one. To be honest I have troubles with the last one as well.

Comment: Did you try induction?

Comment: The suggestion to use induction is a good one. Let $A_k=\sum_{i=1}^ki\times i!$ and let $B_k=(1+k)!-1$.  Show that $A_1=B_1$ and then assume the result holds for $k$ and deduce it for $k+1$.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^k n\ n! \color{red}{\ne}  \sum\limits_{n=1}^k n(n-1)! $ for any $k>1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$n\,n!=(n+1)!-n!$$ so that you have a telescopic sum that equals the last term minus the first, $$(k+1)!-1!$$

Comment: I know that is may be lame question, but can you explain how you get this $$n\,n!=(n+1)!-n!$$, step by step? And why did you go from n to k? Can you by any chance solve this?

Comment: @pzydziak: the identity you wrote in your question is wrong. Review that.

Answer (score 0):

To the OP. One not so difficult way to show this equality is to use induction. You can see it is true for $k=1$. Assume the equality is true for arbitrary $k$, all you need to show now is $(k+1)!-1+(k+1)(k+1)!=(k+2)!-1$, which is little algebra on the left side. From the terms $(k+1)!$ and $(k+1)(k+1)!$ you can factor $((k+1)!$ leaving you with $(k+1)!(1+k+1)$ with that $-1$ tagging along. Can you finish it?